# How do I Rewrite my Code to Run in Parallel?

Tags: r

I have a list of animal tracking data that I've already used to calculate variograms for in R. Since my current setup takes a while to run, it was suggested that I learn to parallelize my code so it will run faster. I've attempted to do so, but I keep running into errors and I'm not sure how to correct the issue.

Here's an example of my current code setup using built in buffalo tracking data from the ctmm package.

```
#Loading libraries
library(ctmm)
library(parallel)

#Reading in the example data associated with the ctmm package
data("buffalo")

#Adding an ID column to all lists
for(i in 1:length(buffalo)){
  buffalo[[i]][7]<-names(buffalo[i])
  names(buffalo[[i]])[7]<-"ID"

}

#Writing a function to calculate variograms for each telemetry object
SVF <- function(x) {
  SVF <- list()
  for (i in 1:length(x)) {    
    SVF[[i]] <- variogram(x[[i]])
    plot(SVF[[i]], main = paste(names(x[i])))
  }
  return(SVF)
}

#Applying the variogram function to the list of telemetry objects 
#(I know this function calculates all variograms six times. Not exactly sure why, 
#possibly something to do with seq_along(), but it doesn't do this for my actual data,
#which is set up slightly differently, and it doesn't affect my example output,
#so I'm leaving it as is )
svf_list<-lapply(seq_along(buffalo), function(i) SVF(buffalo))
names(svf_list)<-names(buffalo)
```

And here's my attempt to parallelize my code

```
#Attempt to parallelize code

#calculate number of cores
no_cores <- detectCores() - 1


#Initiate cluster
cl <- makeCluster(no_cores)

#run function using parLapply
SVF_list <- parLapply(cl, buffalo, function(x) {
  SVF <- list()
  for (i in 1:length(x)) {
    SVF[[i]] <- variogram(x[[i]])
    plot(SVF[[i]], main = paste(names(x[i])))
  }
  return(SVF)
})

#Stop parallelization
stopCluster(cl)
```

When I attempt to run the parLapply function, I get the following error:

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  6 nodes produced errors; first error: invalid 'times' argument
```

Any ideas how to fix my code? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is more complicated than necessary. We can achieve the same results with more straightforward code. You also don't need to parallelize the plotting part. After the variograms are calculated just plot them in single-thread mode.

#### Straightforward Code

```r
library(ctmm)
library(parallel)

data("buffalo")

# Get variograms
buffalo_variograms <- lapply(buffalo, variogram)

# Plot data for each buffalo
par(mfrow = c(3, 2)) # Set up plot convas for 6 plots
mapply(\(x, y) plot(x, main = y),
         buffalo_variograms,
         names(buffalo_variograms))
```

[image]

#### Parallized code

```r
no_cores <- detectCores() - 1
cl <- makeCluster(no_cores)

SVF_list <- parLapply(cl, buffalo, variogram)

stopCluster(cl)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're a lucky Linux user, you can use `parallel::mclapply`.

```
data("buffalo", package='ctmm')

ncpu <- 2L
buffalo_variograms <- parallel::mclapply(buffalo, ctmm::variogram, mc.cores=ncpu)

par(mfrow=c(2, 3))
Map(plot, buffalo_variograms, main=names(buffalo_variograms)) |> invisible()
```

[image]